# How do i find sum $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sin(3^{r-1}\theta)\sec(3^r\theta) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

How do i find sum

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sin(3^{r-1}\theta)\sec(3^r\theta) $$

Needs hint to begin

thanks

Comment: I personally think that the OP made clear the fact that he had no idea how to begin, so I think this question is justified.

Comment: This question is not duplicate at all of question marked as duplicate, it is general case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this can be done through significant amounts of trigonemetric manipulation on $\frac{\sin x}{\cos 3x}$. So first,

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos 3x}= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2 \cdot \sin x \cdot \cos x}{\cos x \cdot \cos 3x}= \frac{1}{2} \cdot  \frac{\sin 2x}{\cos x \cdot \cos 3x}$$
Now, this becomes
$$ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{ \sin(3x - x) }{ \cos x \cdot \cos3x }= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{ \sin 3x \cdot \cos x - \cos 3x \cdot \sin x}{ \cos x \cdot \cos3x}$$
Which is $$ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac {\sin 3x \cdot \cos x}{\cos x \cdot \cos 3x} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\cos 3x \cdot \sin x}{\cos x \cdot \cos 3x}= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left (\frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x} - \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \right )=\frac{\tan 3x-\tan x}{2}$$

So we have $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos 3x}=\frac{\tan 3x-\tan x}{2} \tag{1}$$
So $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sin(3^{r-1}\theta)\sec(3^r\theta) =\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\sin(3^{r-1}\theta)}{\cos(3^r\theta)}=\frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{r=1}^{n}\tan 3^r \theta-\tan 3^{r-1} \theta \right)$$From $(1)$. Note that this is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). You can simplify this nicely.

Comment: Thanks. is this the general method to do such type of questions in which product of trig fucntions are involved